# Connect to user using taskmanager with out their password?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I'm wondering if there is a way to connect to other users using task manager with out their password. Right now I can right click a user under the users tab in task manager and select connect, but I need their password to login. Is there any way to use my administrator credentials to over ride this?

Running a windows server 2012 r2 standerd

Comment: If you're an administrator, you can simply change their password. When you're done, tell them their new password and have them change it on the next login.

Comment: I'm trying not to do that because I may have to access their account fairly often.